# Nextjs Image component does not work with external URL of image source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I have tried using the image component in Next.js with an external URL as a source but getting an error. I have also updated the `next.config.js` file as on the Next.js official docs but still, the same error persists.

Here is the error message:
[image]

Here is the image component

```
<Image
src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638913662180-afc4334cf422?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80"
alt="Coin"
width={500}
height={450}
/>
```

Here is the `next.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['images.unsplash.com']
  },
}
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Have you restarted the dev server?

Comment: No. I did not restart the dev server after doing this. But now I have tried restarting the dev server and it works fine. Thank you ❤ so much.

Comment: Shall I move the comment to the answer & you can close this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Restart** the nextjs server each time you change the config file, `next.config.js`.